# Random Colors jquery boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

My question is:  I have a list of colors that jquery uses to select a random color for the box divs in my HTML.  If you click on the "Random me" button, everything works and random colors are picked for each square.  However, I want to make sure that adjacent squares don't get the same color (i.e. Square 1 color = black, Square 2 color = red, 
Square 3 color = yellow, Square 4 color = purple).  I want each Square to have its own unique color that is selected from a pool of say, 20 colors.  So I don't want red, red, yellow, purple or red, yellow, red, purple, etc.

Below is all my code (HTML with CSS added as a style element in the head) and (jQuery added at the bottom of the page just before the closing body tag).

You guys are awesome.  Thanks in advance for all your help.  Jason

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Square Test</title>

    <!-- CSS styles -->
    <style>
        .nw{background: #f09; top: 0; left: 0; right: 50%; bottom: 50%}

        .ne{background: #f90; top: 0; left: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 50%}

        .sw{background: #009; top: 50%; left: 0; right: 50%; bottom: 0}

        .se{background: #090; top: 50%; left: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 0}

        html, body{width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0}

        div{position: absolute; padding: 1em; border: 1px solid #000}

        div {
            -webkit-box-sixing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #question {
            position: absolute;
            top: 44%;
            left: 37%;
            bottom: 50%;
            color: red;
            width: 30%;
            height: 5%;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 3px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            border-radius: 30px;
        }

        #square1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20%;
            left: 20%;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        #square2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20%;
            left: 70%;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 24px; 
        }

        #square3 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 70%;
            left: 20%;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        #square4 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 70%;
            left: 70%;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 24px; 
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- the divs that the jQuery acts on -->
    <div onclick="change_color(1)" id="div_color_1" class="nw change_color" style="background-color: rgb(224, 216, 200);">
    </div>

    <div onclick="change_color(2)" id="div_color_2" class="ne change_color" style="background-color: rgb(94, 198, 49);">
    </div>

    <div onclick="change_color(3)" id="div_color_3" class="sw change_color" style="background-color: rgb(84, 51, 38);">
    </div>

    <div onclick="change_color(4)" id="div_color_4" class="se change_color" style="background-color: rgb(169, 215, 220);">
    </div>

   <!-- Random me button that selects a random color for each square -->
    <input id="question" type="button" onclick="colorfy_me()" value="Random me">

        <!-- the squares -->
        <p id="square1">Square 1</p>

        <p id="square2">>Square 2</p>

        <p id="square3">>Square 3</p>

        <p id="square4">>Square 4</p>

<!-- jQuery scripts -->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myColors = [
        '#7F8C8D', '#95A5A6', '#BDC3C7', '#003946', '#BDC3C7',
        '#ECF0F1', '#BDC3C7', '#ECF0F1', '#C0392B', '#E74C3C',
        '#D35400', '#E67E22', '#F39C12', '#F1C40F', '#22313f',
        '#2C3E50', '#34495E', '#8E44AD', '#9B59B6', '#2980B9',
        '#3498DB', '#27AE60', '#2ECC71', '#16A085'
    ];

    $(function(){
        $.each(myColors, function(i, v){
            $('#div_color' + (+i + 1)).css('background-color', v);
        })

    })

    function colorfy_me() {

        var colors = {};
            $.each(myColors, function(i, v){
            colors[i] = 0;
        })

        $('div.change_color').each(function() {
            var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * myColors.length);
            $(this).css('background-color', myColors[color]);
            colors[color] = colors[color] + 1;
        });

        $.each(colors, function(i, v){
            $('#div_color' + (+i + 1)).html(colors[i])
        });
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use an array of colours copied from a master, each time you pick a colour , you take it from your array, adjusting your working colour array, that way the colour is not available.

Comment: alexmac, could you explain or show me how to do this?

Comment: Well, you have a master Array say var colors = [ "DeepPink", "OrangeRed", "Gold", "RosyBrown", "Maroon", "cyan", "teal", "navy", "slateblue", "SlateGray"];   Then you can make a copy and use that to take random numbers based on length.  Then pick an element and then remove that element from your working array, on repaint of your windows just reset your working array to the master and redo the random colours. - sorry a bit busy for a full example.

Answer (score 0):

This version of color_me implements the algorithm alexmac is trying to describe.  It removes each color from the copy as it goes so that the shrinking color array contains only unused colors.

```
colorfy_me = function() {
    var colors = myColors.slice(0)

    $('div.change_color').each(function() {
         // find a random color that's not already used.
         var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
         $(this).css('background-color', colors[color]);
         $(this).html( colors[color] )
         colors = colors.slice(0,color-1).concat( 
             colors.slice(color+1,colors.length-1) )
    });

    $.each(colors, function(i, v){
        $('#div_color_' + (+i + 1)).html(colors[i])
    });
}
```

there were a few other issues with your code, so I did have to make a few changes.  See working example on http://jsfiddle.net/cQB38/1/

Defining only colors that are unique, that's trickier.  One option is to break your colors into 4 sets of similar colors, and then pull one random color from each of the 4 sets.  I think it's probably possible to determine how dissimilar two colors are, based on comparing the differences between and sums of their individual red, green, and blue components, but that sounds complicated.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion Dan Farrell seems to work the best.  The only thing I can't figure out is how to stop the hex code from being printed in text on the page?  I'm sure this is simple

Comment: oh, I thought you wanted that :)  That's done by `         $(this).html( colors[color] )
`

Answer (score 0):

assign myColors to a temp array and get color for background-color from temp array then remove the color from temp array using splice method

change your colorfy_me() like following and try

```
function colorfy_me() {

        var colors = {};
            $.each(myColors, function(i, v){
            colors[i] = 0;
        })
        testColor=myColors;
        $('div.change_color').each(function() {
            var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * myColors.length);
            $(this).css('background-color', testColor[color]);          
            testColor.splice(color,1);
            colors[color] = colors[color] + 1;
        });

        $.each(colors, function(i, v){
            $('#div_color' + (+i + 1)).html(colors[i])
        });
    }
```